# observing multiple select menus with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I want to observe multiple select menus and respond to their changes using prototype but only the first menu seems to be observed. This is my code:

```
$('product_options').select('select').invoke("observe","change",optchange);
```

If there are - for example - 3 selects within product_options then it only observes the first, i thought it might be because of invoke so i then tried this:

```
$('product_options').select('select').each(function(sel){
    $(sel).observe("change",optchange);
});
```

Still doesnt work though, any ideas whats wrong?

There's definitely nothing wrong with the selector as a `console.debug()` shows me all the select menus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your JS error console? The below works just fine:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>optchange</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="product_options">
      <select id="o0">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
      </select>
      <select id="o1">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
      </select>
      <select id="o3">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function optchange(e) {
        alert("optchanged");
      }
      $('product_options').select('select').invoke("observe","change", optchange);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: good point, should have checked it with minimum complexity. must be an issue elsewhere. points are yours :)

Comment: Very useful! How can I know in "optchange" which select triggered it ?

Comment: @xain optchange is passed an event object (in the example 'e'). You can ask that for the element that triggered the event. var trigger = e.element()